# How to get serverside file uploading progress in Perfect

Tags: swift, perfect, server-side-swift

I'm trying to create a web page using Perfect(perfect.org), Where users will browse and upload files. Can anyone tell me how can I get the progress of file upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before an official solution released from PerfectlySoft Inc. for this feature request, you could try splitting the file into small pieces and upload them one by one, then merge them back to the server - since there is no such an industrial standard to apply, all other web servers either provide different solutions or simply stay away from it.

Answer (score 1):

[perfect.org-fileUploads](http://perfect.org/docs/fileUploads.html)

Refer above link and Do as-usual concept following in HTML-JS-PHP or HTML-JS-JSP or other programming

In other words
you can receive response status in percentage from server-side and display it to client or put loder while uploading the file

Thank you